# node.js api keep code dry

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, dry

I was wondering , what is the best practice to keep the code DRY when developing node.js api with database calls.

I seems like I'm having alot of repeated code.

For example, look at this:

```
app.get('/api/users_count', function (req,res) {
  pool.connect(function(err, client, done) {
    if(err) {
      return console.error('error fetching client from pool', err);
    }
    client.query('SELECT count(*) FROM users;', function(err, result) {
      done();

      if(err) {
        return console.error('error running query', err);
      }
      res.json({"users count": result.rows[0].count});
    });
  });


});
```

and this:

```
app.get('/api/users/:id', function (req,res) {
  pool.connect(function(err, client, done) {
    if(err) {
      return console.error('error fetching client from pool', err);
    }
    client.query('SELECT name FROM users WHERE id=$1;',req.param.id, function(err, result) {

      done();

      if(err) {
        return console.error('error running query', err);
      }
      res.json({"user name": result.rows[0].name});
    });
  });


});
```

How can I avoid the repeating of error handing , connect call, and just focus on route and query.

Thanks!

Comment: For one, you can use [`pool.query()`](https://github.com/brianc/node-pg-pool#your-new-favorite-helper-method) instead of `connect()/query()/done()`.

Comment: thanks! using api call  and pool.query does the job! 
I think i can use pool.on for common error handling , right?

Comment: The issue with using `pool.on()` for global error handling is that you probably won't be able to send an HTTP response (like a 500) to indicate that an error occurred (since the `on` handler won't have access to `res`).

Comment: so maybe the best will be creating a method that get route, query, and res , like @medet  suggested

Comment: The suggested code does basically the same as when you would be using `pool.query()` (instead of `customPool`). You still need to be handling errors (properly, `return console.log()` will result in stalled requests).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at sample below, should help

```
//Create fn that connects, pulls data, and passes it to callback
function customPool(query, values, callback) {
  pool.connect(function(err, client, done) {
    if(err)
      return callback(err);
    client.query(query, values, function(q_err, result) {
      done();
      if(q_err)
        return callback(q_err);
      callback(null, result.rows);
    });
  }
}

//Reuse it
app.get('/api/users_count', function (req,res) {
  var query = 'SELECT count(*) FROM users;';
  customPool(query, undefined, function(err, rows) {
    if(err)
      return console.error('error fetching client from pool', err);
    res.json({"users count": rows[0].count});
  });
});

app.get('/api/users/:id', function (req,res) {
  var query = 'SELECT name FROM users WHERE id=$1;';
  customPool(query, req.params.id, function(err, rows) { //<-- notice, req.params.id not req.param.id
    if(err)
      return console.error('error fetching client from pool', err);
    res.json({"users name": rows[0].name});
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

For starters, use [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) for database communications, to avoid connecting manually. Then your code will be way simpler, as shown below.

**code 1:**

```
app.get('/api/users_count', function (req, res) {
    db.one('SELECT count(*) FROM users')
        .then(data=> {
            res.json({"users count": +data.count});
        })
        .catch(error=> {
            // should provide a response here also ;)
            console.error(error);
        });
});
```

**code 2:**

```
app.get('/api/users/:id', function (req, res) {
    db.one('SELECT name FROM users WHERE id=$1', +req.param.id)
        .then(user=> {
            res.json({"user name": user.name});
        })
        .catch(error=> {
            // should provide a response here also ;)
            console.error(error);
        });
});
```

Then you can simplify it further, by implementing a generic `request->response` logic, depending on your application's requirements.

Comment: thanks! maybe you can provide links to get more information about request/response , i would like to know about the best practices to that.

Comment: @tzvikaofek it would depend on whether your API for responses can be generalized into one piece of code or not, like i said - it depends on the project's requirements.